# iOS controller ignores albumArtURI

Tags: sonos

Seeing a strange issue for the "Hype Machine" Sonos app where the iOS controller is not displaying album art provided by albumArtURI. The artwork shows up on the OS X controller.

The custom browse icons ARE working in this configuration, but that's a different section, of course.

pmap:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Presentation>
    <PresentationMap type="BrowseIconSizeMap">
        <Match>
            <browseIconSizeMap>
                <sizeEntry size="0" substitution="_legacy.png"/>
                <sizeEntry size="40" substitution="_40.svg"/>
                <sizeEntry size="290" substitution="_290.svg"/>
            </browseIconSizeMap>
        </Match>
    </PresentationMap>
    <PresentationMap type="ArtWorkSizeMap">
      <Match>
        <!-- Default URL provided: http://static-ak.hypem.net/thumbs_new/e1/2207457_120.jpg -->
        <imageSizeMap>
            <sizeEntry size="50" substitution=".jpg"/>
            <sizeEntry size="120" substitution="_120.jpg"/>
            <sizeEntry size="320" substitution="_320.jpg"/>
        </imageSizeMap>         
      </Match>
    </PresentationMap>
    <PresentationMap type="InfoView">
        <Match>
            <MenuItemOverrides>
                <MenuItem FailureStringId="SAVE_TRACK_FAILURE" InProgressStringId="SAVE_TRACK_DURING" MenuItem="AddTrackToFavorites" StringId="SAVE_TRACK" SuccessStringId="SAVE_TRACK_SUCCESS"/>
                <MenuItem FailureStringId="DELETE_TRACK_FAILURE" InProgressStringId="DELETE_TRACK_DURING" MenuItem="RemoveTrackFromFavorites" PromptStringId="DELETE_TRACK_PROMPT" StringId="DELETE_TRACK" SuccessStringId="DELETE_TRACK_SUCCESS"/>
            </MenuItemOverrides>
        </Match>
    </PresentationMap>
    <PresentationMap type="NowPlayingRatings" trackEnabled="true">
        <Match propname="isFav" value="1">
            <Ratings>
                <Rating Id="0" AutoSkip="NEVER" OnSuccessStringId="UNFAV_SUCCESS" StringId="UNFAV">
                    <Icon Controller="icr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_52.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="acr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_52.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="acr-hdpi" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_80.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="macdcr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_40.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="pcdcr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_40.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="cr200" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/on_66.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="universal" LastModified="11:11:11 24 Mar 2014" Uri="http://sonos-img.ws.sonos.com/love-selected.svg"/>
                </Rating>
            </Ratings>
        </Match>
        <Match propname="isFav" value="0">
            <Ratings>
                <Rating Id="1" AutoSkip="NEVER" OnSuccessStringId="FAV_SUCCESS" StringId="FAV">
                    <Icon Controller="icr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_52.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="acr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_52.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="acr-hdpi" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_80.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="macdcr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_40.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="pcdcr" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_40.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="cr200" LastModified="14:00:00 17 Dec 2012" Uri="http://hypem.com/images/sonos/off_66.png"/>
                    <Icon Controller="universal" LastModified="11:11:11 24 Mar 2014" Uri="http://sonos-img.ws.sonos.com/love-unselected.svg"/>
                </Rating>
            </Ratings>
        </Match>
    </PresentationMap>
    <PresentationMap type="Search">
        <Match>
            <SearchCategories>
                <Category id="artists" mappedId="SART" />
                <Category id="tracks" mappedId="STRK" />
                <CustomCategory mappedId="SBLG" stringId="Blogs" />
            </SearchCategories>
        </Match>
    </PresentationMap>
</Presentation>
```

Example response:

```
<ns1:mediaMetadata>
        <ns1:id>TRACK:2crvj</ns1:id>
        <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
        <ns1:title>Can I (Tez Cadey Remix)</ns1:title>
        <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
        <ns1:trackMetadata>
            <ns1:artist>Alina Baraz &amp; Galimatias</ns1:artist>
            <ns1:duration>185</ns1:duration>
            <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.hypem.net/thumbs_new/71/2808433_120.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
            <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
        </ns1:trackMetadata>
        <ns1:dynamic>
            <ns1:property>
                <ns1:name>isFav</ns1:name>
                <ns1:value>0</ns1:value>
            </ns1:property>
        </ns1:dynamic>
    </ns1:mediaMetadata>
```

Any idea what is incorrect about this configuration?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: For those curious, a solution that worked here is to provide ArtWorkSizeMap entries that match exactly what the controllers require, even if the subsequent image size doesn't match the advertised size.

This entry made the images start showing up:

```
<imageSizeMap>
    <sizeEntry size="50" substitution=".jpg"/>  
    <sizeEntry size="80" substitution="_120.jpg"/>   
    <sizeEntry size="120" substitution="_120.jpg"/>   
    <sizeEntry size="180" substitution="_320.jpg"/>  
    <sizeEntry size="300" substitution="_320.jpg"/>  
    <sizeEntry size="600" substitution="_320.jpg"/>  
    <sizeEntry size="1000" substitution="_320.jpg"/>  
    <sizeEntry size="1500" substitution="_320.jpg"/>  
</imageSizeMap>
```

Comment: Curious, did you run the self test located here:  http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/222

Comment: I know it's working in the mac controller you mention, but just starting with basics.

Comment: @JeffTorgerson The self-test passes fully, just with some warnings about lack of i18n strings.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up on this.  We have updated the documentation on the portal  located here:  http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/366

Anthony, it seems if you use this URI as the base, everything should work:
http://static.hypem.net/thumbs_new/71/2808433.jpg

(or removing the 50 replacement and letting Sonos re-size at run-time would work)